# How to install screenfetch on Alpine linux?

Tags: alpine-linux

I'd like to install screenfetch on Alpine Linux.

How ever all I can find is a dead link on Google:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/screenfetch-doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `screenfetch` package is no longer available on Alpine repositories, you could install it yourself, as described in the project's [Github page](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/wiki/Installation). It's easy:

1. First, install bash: `apk add bash`
2. Then, follow the install instructions:

> - Download the latest source at https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch:
>   `wget -O screenfetch-dev https://git.io/vaHfR`
> - In a terminal, make the file executable by doing the following:
>   `chmod +x screenfetch-dev`
> - Then, either keep it there, or move it to somewhere in your $PATH to make it available without having to use the full path to the script.